# IOS show facebook wall and images

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, photo, facebook-wall

I'm making an app for my favorite café in my neighborhood. I want to show the images and wall posts of the café in the app. I'm new to ios development.  When I search on the web everybody is talking about posting images and wall items. But I just want to show the post and the albums/images. Can anybody help me with some kind of tutorial or something.

Comment: Well where exactly are you having troubles?

Comment: Well, I don't know where to start :)... Like I said, everybody on the net is talking about posting. I just want to show it.

Comment: Ok... Are you able to make calls to the API and get information about  the café's page? Like to query `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID` ?

Comment: I don't know which url I need to query... But I'll give it a try and have a look at the result i get from https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID. It's just an url request? The page is http://www.facebook.com/pages/Ecziteria/191604563157?fref=ts, so i suppose 191604563157 is the page_id.

Comment: I'm getting an error {
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
} for https://graph.facebook.com/191604563157. For my own user I get some data. Is this because this is not a facebook user but a facebook place?